# how to check if field is true in another class

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, hidden-field

I am displaying a Gridview that has an option show more details. When this option is selected a second GridView opens.
There is a hidden field which is set to false when the page is first run.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfDetailsShown" runat="server" Value="false" />
```

When the user clicks on the show more details button I set the hiddenfield to true

```
function ShowAll()
        {
            $(".ShowHide").each(function () {
                if ($(this).html() == "Show") {
                    document.getElementById('<%= hfDetailsShown.ClientID %>').value = true; 
                    $(this).html("Hide");
                    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td colspan = '999' style='padding:0px'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
                }
            });
        }
```

Now in another class I want to check if hfDetailsShown is true. How do I call hfDetailsShown in another class?

```
if (hfDetailsShown == true)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Try using the Url.Action method with the parameter.

Comment: try `"true"` instead of `true`. and check like `hfDetailsShown == "true"`

Comment: Are you doing the check client side or server side. Since you mention class I'm going to assume server-side. You don't check if it's visible from a class, having an object reach out like that to find a control violates some of the OOP principles. Instead you would pass in the value of that control to your class as a property or a parameter on your method call that way the object is operating on itself with the data directly available and related to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowAll()
        {
            $(".ShowHide").each(function () {
                if ($(this).html() == "Show") {
                    document.getElementById('<%= hfDetailsShown.ClientID %>').value = "true"; 
                    $(this).html("Hide");
                    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td colspan = '999' style='padding:0px'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
                }
            });
        }

if (document.getElementById('<%= hfDetailsShown.ClientID %>').value== "true")
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you'd like to check the value of hfDetailsShown.

var yourRequestedField = document.getElementById('<%= hfDetailsShown.ClientID %>').value;